# Can't get my Geospatial Query to Work. Querying Mongo in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

As soon as a User logs in his/or her location is reported. And continues to report the current users location every 15 minutes there on. Or atleast until their session is over.A users location is read into the Database with the Locate method. It is stored in the location array in the database associated with that specific user. And this is all working fine.

A users location will be read out of the database with the scan method.

I was wondering how to create a 2dsphere around location.coordinates. I know I have to target location.coordinates so mongo knows to treat it as a 2dsphere. So I know I have to use User.ensureIndex({location: "2dsphere"}). My issues/ questions are:

1st) Should it be User.ensureIndex("location.coordinate": 2dsphere) or ("location": 2dsphere). And would this go at the top of the app.js.

2nd) In my scan method I'm trying to create logic and query for documents with a username that matches in addition to being within 300 meters. So lastly my question is my last Mongo query structured correctly

Here's what my mongo Schema looks like:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  location: 
    {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [Number, Number],
      datetime: Date
  },
  points: {type:Number, default:10000},
  imageUrl: {type:String, default:'/img/gravatar.jpg'}
});
```

This is how my app.js is set up:

```
var User = require('../models/users.js');


var userController = {

 locate: function (req, res) {

  var data = req.body;
  var date = new Date();
  var username = req.user.username;

  User.findOne({username:username}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return handleErr(err);

    find = {
      coordinates: [data.longitude, data.latitude],
      datetime: date
    };

    user.location.push(find);
    user.save();

   });

 },

 scan: function (req, res) {

  var date = new Date();
  var twentyb4 = date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes - 15);

  User.find({"datetime": {$gte: twentyb4}}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return handleErr(err);

    for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {

    //return users other than current user
    if(req.user.username !== user[i].username){


       User.find({$and: [{username: user[i].username}, {$near:   {$geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [ req.user.longitude, req.user.latiude ]}, $maxDistance: 300, $minDistance: 0}}]}, function(err, data){
        if (err) return handleErr(err);


          console.log(data.username);

        });

      }


    }

  });      

};
```

So ultimately what the scan function is to do is find all users in the database not including the current user. And then it filters to get just those users that have logged in within the last 20 minutes. And then I filter it down one more time comparing the last reported location of the other users compared to that of the current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the working solution:

I needed to have:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  location:
      {
        type: { type: String, default: "Point" },
        coordinates: [Number, Number],
        datetime: Date
      },
  email: {
    type: String
  }
})


userSchema.index({ "location.coordinates": "2dsphere"});  //In my model
```

This is my controller in Node (server):

```
scan: function (req, res) {

    var date = new Date();
    var minusmin = date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - 20);


    User.find({ "location.datetime": {$gte: minusmin}}, function (err, user) {

      if (err) return handleErr(err);


      for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {

        //return users other than current user
        if(req.user.username !== user[i].username){



          User.find({ username: user[i].username, "location.coordinates": { $nearSphere: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ req.user.location.coordinates[0], req.user.location.coordinates[1] ]}, $maxDistance: 300 } } }, function(err, data){
              if (err) return handleErr(err);


              console.log(data);


          });


        }


      }

      res.send(user);

    });

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is wrong, you need to fix this:

```
  location: 
    {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [Number, Number],
      datetime: Date
  },
```

To this:

```
  location: {
      "type": { "type": String, "default": "Point" },
      "coordinates": [Number, Number],
      "datetime": Date
  },
```

As the "type" keywork is being confused, and "Point" is not a mongoose datatype.

You also need an index defined for geoSpatial queries:

```
userSchema.index({ "location": "2dsphere" });
```

Then your query is quite simple ( you don't need `$and` here as all query arguments are an "and" condition already ), and you really want [**`$nearSphere`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/) here with real world coordinates:

```
User.find({ 
    "username": user[i].username,
    "$nearSphere": {
        "$geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [ parseFloat(req.user.longitude), parseFloat(req.user.latiude) ]
        }, 
        "$maxDistance": 300, 
        "$minDistance": 0
    }
}, function(err, data) {

});
```

Being careful to watch that `parseFloat` in there as well, as I cannot recall offhand if Mongoose actually has the smarts to "type cast" with a `$nearSphere` query like this.

I would also suggest "don't loop" here, and just get all users other than the current usename all at once. Simple with some pre-filtering and the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator:

```
// Filter out username values only except for the current user
var otherUsers = user.map(function(u) {
    return u.username
}).filter(function(u) { return u != req.user.username });

if ( otherUsers.length > 0 ) {

    User.find({ 
        "username": { "$in": otherUsers },
        "$nearSphere": {
            "$geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ parseFloat(req.user.longitude), parseFloat(req.user.latiude) ]
            }, 
            "$maxDistance": 300, 
            "$minDistance": 0
        }
    }, function(err, data) {

    });

} else {
   // no-one else is within the time :(
}
```

Now you tested all the other users in a single query, so you don't need to bother with looping results and the related asynchronous control that you really would require otherwise as well.

Comment: I got it working using the for loop. However I wanted to also get it working doing the loop before the mongo query like you had said. My question is does $in loop through otherUsers (and treat its value as an array/expect an array). Bc I need it to loop through the array and test each individual element as its own entity.

Comment: @irusHacker As I said, you don't need a loop. You do you initial query for the users by date and that returns as an array of documents. Then the `map()` operation just extracts those "username" values only as an array. The `.filter()` checks to remove the current user from that list. The `$in` condition takes an array of arguments to filter by, being all the "username" values you want.

Comment: @irusHacker Additionally, your own self-posted and now accepted answer is incorrect. It is the **schema** that needs correcting just as I have shown at the begining. Also since you have directly indexed "location.coordinates" and not the top level "location", then the geopatial data is now considered as "legacy coodinate pairs" and not a "GeoJSON" object as you are storing it. The consequence of this is all your distances will now be reported in "radians" rather than "meters". The correct thing to do is follow exactly what I posted in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My schema includes your changes I just forgot to include that in the accepted answer.  In response to not using an official GeoJSON object. Why would it be measured in radians. Thats not even a measurement of distance but rather an angle

Comment: @irusHacker It's also a measure of curvature between points. With coordinates as an array and not as a GeoJSON object you need to do the math. And for the record the schema fix **is** the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create an index once (ensureIndex is deprecated, the same functionality is present in [createIndex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex). Since you're using mongoose, just define the index on your schema, e.g.

`userSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});`

Your query is almost there, here's the correct version.

```
var geoJSONpoint = {
   type: 'Point',
   coordinates: [
       req.user.longitude,
       req.user.latitude
   ]
}

User.find({ username: user[i].username, location: { $near: { $geometry: geoJSONpoint, $maxDistance: 300 } } })
...
```